# Need help in templating jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2, rendering

How to remove a word preceeds after data-us here and print `data-us.example.com` using regex_replace in jinja2.

```
mouliveera@xxxx$ echo data-us-b.example.com | sed "s/-[a-z]*\(\.example.com\)/\1/"
data-us.example.com

mouliveera@xxxx$ echo data-us-lb.example.com | sed "s/-[a-z]*\(\.example.com\)/\1/"
data-us.example.com

mouliveera@xxxx$ echo data-us-a.example.com | sed "s/-[a-z]*\(\.example.com\)/\1/"
data-us.example.com
```

Comment: I tried with `endpoint=data-us-lb.example.com`; 
{{endpoint | regex_replace("s/-[a-z]*(\." + example.com + ")", "\\1")}}, but no luck.

Comment: Your question seems to be about `sed`, but you've tagged it with `ansible` and `jinja2`.  Where does Ansible enter into this question?

Comment: I just used sed to show my requirement. I need help in getting the same using regex_replace in jinja2.

Comment: Just as @larsks said, you'll want to actually include the literal playbook you are trying to use, because in yaml the style of quoting matters **a lot**. Even in your `sed` example, you should be using single quotes because a backslash inside doublequotes is interpreted differently than inside single ones (just like Matt P's answer, which arrived in the middle of my comment ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

Using the example you provided where `endpoint=data-us-lb.example.com`, then the direct translation for regex_replace is:

`"{{ endpoint | regex_replace('-[a-z]*(.example.com)$', '\\1') }}"`